# I have a stored procedure using Microsoft Sql Server Studio. I have months being stored as 01, 02, 03, 04 ..... etc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

> This is my stored procedure. Is there something i can add to this that will return the months as names instead of 01, 02, 03,.... Or can i somehow use a switch case or something in c#.. I am using Visual Studio 2017 c# asp.net mvc.

```
Select distinct statementMonth
from dbo.ClientStatement_Inventory
order by statementMonth asc
```

Comment: This sounds like the wrong thing to do... the database is there to worry about the data. How to *present* that data (mapping numbers to names, etc) is a UI concern. So: it feels like you should worry about this *at the UI layer*, not the stored procedure

Comment: That makes sense.. So using a switch statement to change the 01 to January.... would probably be my best bet? Thank you

Comment: or DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName

Answer (score 1):

You *could* build a big case expression with 12 branches.

A simpler solution to turn a literal string like `'01'`, `'02'`, ... to a month name is to use string concatenation and date functions, like:

```
datename(month, '2020' + statementMonth + '01') as statementMonthName
```

Or, if you actually have a number rather than a string:

```
datename(month, datefromparts(2020, statementMonth, 1)) as statementMonthName
```

Comment: So, if im trying to have these go through my ViewModel as checkboxes. so when people check the boxes it will only grab files for 2020? Will I need to do this for each year? I need the past ten years.